# Get data from the id and display it on a table Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have a table with some products, the table has only a few attributes and there's a button to get a full view. Now what I want to do is, when that button is clicked, display a dialog that shows the same table, but only that specific product that was clicked, so only the details of that product.
Here's the function from the main table. I'm using a simple table, not a mat table, and the problem is that when I try to use a function to get that data on a table, it's giving me some error. The function is below as well.  Any assistance would be more than welcome.

```
getFullDetails(pk) {
    const dialogRef=this.dialog.open(ProductsListComponent, {
      width:'700px',
      data:{
        id:pk,
      }
    })
```

On the ProductListComponent.ts:

```
    const id = this.data.id;
    if(id) {
      this.ordersService.getByID(id)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(response => this.productList=response);
```

The errors that `=response` gets me are: `'Type 'ProductData' is not assignable to type 'ProductData[]` and `Type 'Product Data' is missing the following properties from type 'ProductData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more`

Answer (score 0):

That means `productList` is probably declared like this:

```
productList: ProductData[];
```

While you actually want:

```
product: ProductData;
```

As you are displaying the details of a single product.

```
const id = this.data.id;
if(id) {
  this.ordersService.getByID(id)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(response => this.product = response);
```

Comment: Gotcha, uhm, makes sense but when I go and change it on my ngIf* in the table, i get this error ```Type ProductData is not assignable to type (ProductData & NgIterable<T>) | undefined | null ```

Comment: are you trying to iterate productData with ngFor ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same variable for listing and displaying individual items, there might be a problem. Because Typescript expects an array of *ProductData* type.